# Why are counters necessary to describe the quantity of objects?

Tags: counters, comparative-linguistics

Why are counters (助数詞) necessary to describe the numerical quantity of objects in Japanese?

I'm interested in the linguistic explanation specifically, but also curious as to how strict those who are fluent tend to be about it in colloquial conversation.

Comment: We do have counters in English, too, although we don't have as many of them and native speakers aren't as aware of them as "counters", per se.  One everyday example: why do we say _"a **pair** of pants"_?  (Historically, I get that "pants" a.k.a. "trousers" weren't joined in the middle, so you had one piece for each leg.  But nowadays, it's just an odd leftover relic. :) )

Comment: `Why are counters necessary`>> 助数詞がなかったら、「 **３歩**歩いて**２歩**下がる」「 **何名**様ですか -- **３人**です」とかが使えないし、「 **一口**ちょうだい」「 **一個**ちょうだい」「 **一切れ**ちょうだい」「 **一杯**ちょうだい」とかの違いがわからないし、「 **第一球**投げました！」「なにか**一枚**羽織りなさい」「 **一発**やらせろ！」とか言うときに困るからですかね・・。あと、「尾、丁、さく、切れ」とかがないと、マグロも数えられないし不便ですよね・・・。

Comment: I wrote articles about it, if you please. (1) http://lang-8.com/1258954/journals/271307152612572000329247151022127481902 (2)http://lang-8.com/1258954/journals/7624019284048181065485904054774957102

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Counters aren't necessary any more in Japanese than gendered nouns are in romance languages, e.g. *la* vache vs. *le* chat.

English has something extremely similar to counters called [Collective Nouns](http://users.tinyonline.co.uk/gswithenbank/collnoun.htm). When you see several fish, you call it a "school of fish". You wouldn't say a "school of wolves", you'd say a "pack of wolves".

Are these necessary? Anyone could just say a "group of fish/wolves", but it simply wouldn't sound right to our ears. That's the same way it works in Japanese, to say 一枚のペン simply wouldn't sound right, even though you could easily say 一つのペン.

Comment: Then there are the odd ones: _a ministry of crows_, _a lunacy of werewolves_, and my personal favorite, _an itself of Yahwehs_.  (For the latter two, see http://wondermark.com/566/)

Comment: I suppose there might be cases [where 一枚のペン would work](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/919/864/223/1251084180653_hz_myalibaba_web18_10367.jpg).  :)

Comment: I don't think counters are that much like collective nouns (which are often just made up things no one would even say, anyway), they are more like "one sheet of paper" or "three slices of pizza/cake/pie".

Comment: As @EiríkrÚtlendi implied, the answerer got the counter for pen wrong, since 枚 is used for sheet-like objects, whereas 本, the counter for long objects, is appropriate.

Comment: @Paul, some of the obscure collective nouns are indeed variable and bordering on made-up.  However, many collective nouns are used extensively: _a flock of birds_, _a school of fish_, _a pack of dogs_, _an oppressiveness of politicians_.  (Well, maybe not that last one. :) )

Comment: @Paul, yes English does have a few counters but I don't like to use those as examples cause they are few and far between, you can also naturally replace your examples with a "piece" of paper/pie/cake/pizza/etc. Native English speakers usually remark that not using the right collective noun "sounds wrong", which is analogous to what I've heard from native Japanese speakers in regards to counters. It's always been my go-to analogy when explaining counters to an English speaker.

Comment: @bcloutier Fair enough, but "piece" is also a counter, just a broadly generic one. You still can't use the "wrong" counter ("one sheet of pizza" is not going to fly). I also can't think of another obvious way to count the word "cattle" other than by "head".

Answer (score 4):

Counter words are not necessary, but many languages do use them. My favourite counter in English for illustrative purposes is "sheet(s)", as in "two sheets of paper". With other counters like "two *bottles* of beer", you can sometimes get away with "two beers", but "two papers" doesn't mean "two sheets of paper" (although it can now mean "two publications").

While in English counter words ("[classifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_(linguistics))") are usually only used for [mass nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_nouns) (i.e. things where it is unclear what "one [thing]" is), in Japanese counting items/people/days/etc. is *always* done using [Japanese counter words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word). (One could say that Japanese has no [count nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun), so that all nouns are mass nouns/non-count nouns.)

There is some level of flexibility in what counter to choose for which item. For checking which counter to use, one can consult [数え方の辞典](https://www.shogakukan.co.jp/books/09505201), which gives explanatory notes to each counter, e.g.

> **かみ**【紙】
>
> **枚【まい】、葉【よう】、本、ロール、巻き【まき】、片【ひら】、束【たば】**
>
> 「葉【よう】」は葉【は】のように手に取ることができる程度の大きさで、折りたたまれていない紙を数える語です。FAX紙のようなひと巻きの紙は「本」「ロール」「巻き」で数えます。「片」はメモ用紙や紙切れ、紙吹雪などを数える語です。束ねたものは「束」で数えます。
>
> **帖【じょう】、締め【しめ】、連【れん】、丸【まる】**
>
> 小売単位は「帖」を用います。半紙20枚、美濃紙【みのがみ】は48枚で「1帖」です。和紙2000枚を「ひと締め」、洋紙1000枚を「1連」といいます。「丸」は、和紙の取引単位です。

Just like we have to use a counter for paper in English. Roughly corresponding to the above, we have

> a **sheet** of paper, a **scrap** of paper, a **piece** of paper, a **roll** of paper
>
> a **ream** of paper, one [**quire**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_paper_quantity) of paper, one **bale** of paper, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @bcioutier's great answer, it is somewhat wrong to assume there are  counters only in Japanese or there are no counters in English as @Eiríkr Útlendi commented. I am not saying you are assuming so.

English uses a couple to indicate two. And there are a half a dozen to mean six, a dozen for twelve, a score for 20, a gross (12 dozens) for 144, etc.

There are also special words for people using prefixes for each number.

> Soloist, duet, trio, quartet, quintet, sextet, septet, octet.

Your question,

> Why are counters (助数詞) necessary to describe the numerical quantity of
>   objects in Japanese?

Japanese needs counters to describe quantity of objects, some are complicated, some are not. But that's the way the language has evolved for thousands of years as English has on its own way. If someone asks why English uses *duet* and *trio* instead of just 'two people' and 'three people', you will answer because they have specific meaning to indicate the number of people in music or entertainment.

> how strict those who are fluent tend to be about it in colloquial
>   conversation.

It will depend on each native speaker. There are some counters which are strictly followed and some are not.

For more information, you can read the link on [Words for numbers in English](http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/numbers/words/intro.htm) and [Japanese counter word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word).